# Having trouble understanding enumerability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From my book it states that a set is enumerable if there is a procedure which eventually yields as outputs exactly the words in the set. I can see that an example of enumerability is the set of prime numbers. But could someone describe/provide an example of a set which is not enumerable and how to go about proving a set is not enumerable?

Thanks!

Comment: What a disgusting definition.

Comment: I know why you are having trouble.

Comment: As long as you believe the Church-Turing thesis the definition isn't that bad really.:)

Answer (score 1):

Non-enumerability of a set is almost always proved by reducing it to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). This is the question of whether or not a given Turing machine halts on a given input. There are many other undecidable problems (and thus unenumerable sets), for example the word problem for finitely presented groups, but the proof of their undecidability is pretty much always done by reducing them to the halting problem.

Answer (score 0):

An enumerable set is one that is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. The set of prime numbers is enumerable, since you can define
$$p_1=2, \quad p_n= \min\{ a>p_{n-1}:  a \text{ is prime}\}, \text{ for }n\geq 2,$$
that is, $p_n$ is the ordered list of primes in increasing order. Since the set of prime numbers is infinite, this is a bijection, so the set of prime numbers is enumerable. The same happens with $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}^k$, and many more.

An example of non-enumerable set is the Cantor set: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Cardinality.

Comment: I think you are using a different definition of enumerable then given by the OP. Since his definition (vague as it is) specifically mentions there being a procedure which yields the elements of the set, this is not the definition of countable. There are many countable sets such that no procedure is capable of listing them. An example is the set of TM's that halt or $\omega_1^{CK}$.